# Is a Cessna 162 safe to fly if engine RPM drops by 160 on one magneto?

Tags: general-aviation, piston-engine

On a Cessna 162, during engine runup I switch to one mag, and the engine RPM dropped by 50, but on the other mag the RPM dropped by 160 while the POH says maximum allowable drop is 150. Is this plane safe to fly for local pattern work?  The only cause is just a "dirty" spark plug right?  I mean both mags are working at least.

Comment: There's a little unwritten rule in aviation; Don't do anything you wouldn't want to show up on an accident report - Do you really want "Pilot continued to departure in aircraft even though they were aware that it was not operating within the limits....... blah blah blah" to _ever_ show up?

Comment: "maximum allowable drop" seems self-explanatory to me...

Comment: A 10 RPM exceedance would not stop me if the engine ran smoothly on that mag, ran smoothly at higher power on that mag, and the differential between the mags was OK. You're within the +/- tolerance of the tach itself.  I would certainly do a high power mag check, and even do another mag check during the climb at a safe altitude while at climb power. If there are mag problems they will be readily apparent at high power settings. If doing multiple trips or legs, I don't do mag checks after first flight of the day.

Comment: Never knowingly violate an aircraft limitation.  If it says 150 max drop, the aircraft is unairworthyy if it drops more.  It will void any insurance poilcy and you can lose your certificate if there is an incident or accident.

Comment: A student of mine took off once on only one mag.  The switch was in LEFT or RIGHT not BOTH.  About five minutes into the departure, the engine began to run rough.  Only switching to both mags solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

The engine is not performing within the limits specified in your POH. Unless some document gives a different limit for "just in the local traffic pattern," then by taking it up you'd be intentionally violating the manufacturer's prescribed operating limitations for the aircraft. While you might "get away with it," you'd have zero excuse if anything were to go wrong or if a Fed were to find out what you'd been doing.

POH limitations aren't optional.

If it is in fact just a dirty spark plug, it shouldn't take a mechanic long to make everything right.

Answer (score 4):

A fouled plug will usually cause rough running on the single mag because you almost never have all 4 plugs fouled the same, so one cylinder will drop out first. It's usually the bottom plugs, where lead metal from the avgas forms as beads in the insulator well of the plug, eventually bridging the center electrode insulator.

A smooth running mag drop out of limits suggests something more upstream, in the mag itself, like an ignition timing issue or ignition coil problems, that sort of thing, that causes a lack of power on all cylinders. For example, the internal ignition points wear down, both from contact erosion and cam follower wear, and the wear causes the timing to drift in the retarded direction, reducing power very gradually.

Note that there is normally another limit you didn't mention with traditional mags, the differential between the two mag check values, usually 75 RPM. So borderline exceedance of the max drop like that I might let go, where it's a case of trying to parse 10 RPM on the gauge and maybe parallax error is skewing the reading you think you see, but you also have exceeded the 75 RPM differential between the mags, so the exceedance is pretty clear cut.

Normally the next step is to run the power higher, say to 2000-2200 RPM (try to do it on grass), and lean the mixture to  rich side of roughness, and let it go 15 seconds or so like that, then try the mag check at 1700 RPM again.  Often you'll find it passes if the plugs just had a bit of carbon that gets burned off.  That's a scenario your instructor should take you through, because it could make the difference between being stranded away somewhere on a cross country, and making it home with a normally running engine.